# Should every table have a single-field surrogate/artificial primary key?

Tags: database-design, primary-key, surrogate-key

I understand one benefit of surrogate/artificial keys in general - they do not change and that can be very convenient. This is true whether they are single or multiple field - as long as they are 'artificial'.

However, it sometimes seems to be a matter of policy to have an auto-incrementing integer field as the primary key of each table. Is this always the best idea to have such a **single-field** key and why (or why not)?

To be clear, this question is not about artificial vs natural - but about whether all artificial keys should be **single-field**

Comment: see also http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112632/1396

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/204521/32523

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

I'd say there are certainly cases when single-field keys are inferior to compound keys, **at least for the purpose of foreign keys**. That is not to say you should not have a single-field surrogate key as well if you prefer, but I personally prefer the key that is most often used as the target of a foreign key to be called the primary key

I'll attempt to illustrate my point in the the following examples, in which:

- `brand` is car marque, eg Ford, Toyota etc
- `dealer` is a physical dealership, tied to a brand (eg a Ford dealership only selling Fords)
- `model` is the type of car eg Ford Focus, Ford Fiesta etc
- `stock` is the current forecourt car count for each dealership

---

If we create a single-field surrogate key for `dealer` and `model` as follows:

```
create table brand( brand_id integer primary key );

create table dealer( dealer_id integer primary key, 
                     brand_id integer references brand )

create table model( model_id integer primary key, 
                    brand_id integer references brand )

create table stock( model_id integer references model, 
                    dealer_id integer references dealer, 
                    quantity integer,
                      primary key(model_id, dealer_id) )
```

then it is possible to insert a row into `stock` that links a Ford `dealer` to a "Toyota" model. Adding `brand_id references brand` to `stock` only makes the problem worse. On the other hand if we keep the foreign key as part of the primary key as follows:

```
create table brand( brand_id integer primary key );

create table dealer( brand_id integer references brand, 
                     dealer_id integer, 
                       primary key(brand_id, dealer_id) )

create table model( brand_id integer references brand, 
                    model_id integer, 
                      primary key(brand_id, model_id) )

create table stock( brand_id integer, 
                    model_id integer, 
                    dealer_id integer, 
                    quantity integer,
                      primary key(brand_id, model_id, dealer_id),
                      foreign key(brand_id, model_id) references model,
                      foreign key(brand_id, dealer_id) references dealer )
```

now the rule that "Ford" dealers can only stock "Ford" cars is enforced naturally by the model.

Note that in the 'composite keys' example, `dealer_id` may or may not be unique, according to preference. It does not need to be unique (ie an alternate key), but very little is lost by making it so (perhaps a little storage space) and it can be very handy so that is the way I usually set it up, eg:

```
create table dealer( brand_id integer references brand, 
                     dealer_id serial unique, 
                       primary key(brand_id, dealer_id) )
```

Answer (score 30):

I'm going to say **no, not always, but most of the time yes.**.

These are some circumstances in which you don't need a surrogate or artificial key:

- **Pure intersection tables**. If there is *no* risk of the
  intersection being the target of a foreign key and if there is little
  or no risk of the intersection attracting independent attributes
  (i.e. something other than FK's to the two parent tables) then you
  can get away with using the combination of FKs as the PK with fair
  confidence.
- **Lookup tables with static business keys**. If you have a lookup
  table with a unique business key which is fixed externally to your
  business and which has *zero chance of ever changing* for any
  practical purpose, then using the business key directly can make
  things simpler.  An example might be a list of state or province
  codes or a list of ANSI standard numbers, etc.
- **Tables containing data consolidated from multiple, independent
  sources**.  If your system has many sources of data that must be
  shoehorned together into a single table, say at head office, then
  sometimes you need a compound key that includes the source system key
  value and a code indicating what the source system was.

There are also some situations where the old-faithful monotonically increasing integer surrogate key is not ideal.  You can have keys that are alphanumeric surrogates.  These could include:

- Situations where you need to merge data from multiple, independent
  sources.  To avoid key collisions you might use GUIDs instead of
  IDENTITY keys.
- Situations where you are forced to use non-numeric key
  representations.  Let's say you've got a license plate database. 
  Your key could be the alphanumeric value instead of a pure number.
- Situations where some external requirement forces you to apply
  compression to your key value.  Instead of using 10 digits for an
  int32 you can use six base 36 digits.

Why most of the time yes?  The most fundamental answer to that question is that it is pure hell if you ever need to modify a primary key value on any table.  Since *almost* anything a user can see or touch is conceivably subject to an update at some point, using a visible key value is inviting pure hell.  Using a surrogate key will keep you from falling into this trap.

Having said that, remember that there is room for YAGNI in applying this concept.  You don't need to go forcing code tables with IDENTITY keys into every nook and cranny of your schema, just in case someone decides that the symbol for male gender in your employee table needs to change from M to X or something silly.

Answer (score 14):

"it depends"

Yes: Surrogate IDENTITY/AUTONUMBER fields are good when the natural key is wide and non-numeric. Note: this assumes the conflation of "PK" and clustered index that occurs by default in SQL Server and Sybase etc

No: many/many tables when the 2 parent keys suffice. Or when the natural key is short and fixed length eg currency code

Of course, a braindead ORM (read: (n)Hibernate) may trump these rules...

Edit: reading question again

A many/many table with 2 surrogate parent keys will have a multiple column PK. 
However, it doesn't need another surrogate column.

If a table does have a surrogate (IDENTITY etc) key then it doesn't need to be multiple column.

You can have a super key that includes the surrogate but this would be to enforce other rules (eg [subtypes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/non-unique-multicolumn-foreign-key/1764#1764))