# Should I record ID numbers in a table where I record who look whom profile page

Tags: mysql, uniqueidentifier

This is how I have designed:

```
visitorID
visitedprofileID
datetime
```

Is it a good idea to add an ID (primary key) to the table, I mean recordID (primary key).

(MySQL with PHP)

Comment: Is `date` type `datetime`?

Comment: @JackDouglas, yes, it is datetime

Comment: You might be interested in this thread: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/should-every-table-have-a-single-field-surrogate-artificial-primary-key

Answer (score 1):

I think your two choices here are:

1. make the `(visitorID,visitedprofileID)` combination a primary key
2. add a `recordID` as primary key

If the table is InnoDB (or it will be in the future for Foreign Key usage), I would go with the second option. Given the way [InnoDB handles indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html) by adding the primary key to secondary indexes for lookup, if you ever wanted to add an index on datetime, the single field would result in a smaller index.

Comment: +1 for InnoDB info and smaller index observation. BTW Option 1 would be great for MyISAM since you could auto_increment visitorID sequentially within visitedprofileID.