# How to use Unique key via combinations of table fields?

Tags: mysql, insert, unique-constraint, uniqueidentifier

Take a look at the following sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dacb5/1

```
CREATE TABLE contacts 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20), 
     network_id int,
     network_contact_id int
    );

INSERT INTO contacts
(name, network_id, network_contact_id)
VALUES
('John', 4, 10),
('Alex', 4, 11),
('Bob', 4, 12),
('Jeff', 4, 45),
('Bill', 7, 11),
('Walter', 7, 45),
('Jessie', 7, 360) ;
```

I have a basic table of contacts. The `network_id` and `network_contact_id` fields contain id numbers that link to other tables.

I want to be able to run `INSERT IGNORE` queries to this table, but I want to use the combination of the `network_id` and `network_contact_id` as the unique key to match against.

So for example, if I tried to insert a contact that had `network_id = 4` and `network_contact_id = 12`, the `INSERT IGNORE` query would see that entry already exists, and ignore any error that was thrown.

So basically, `network_id` is not unique. `network_contact_id` is not unique. But the combination of the two is unique. How do I set this up? Would I have to have a single other field that is the concatenated values of the two other fields? Or is there a way to setup the keys for this table so it will do what I need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 name varchar(20), 
 network_id int,
 network_contact_id int, 
 UNIQUE KEY (`network_id`, `network_contact_id`)
);
```

Comment: OMG Both your answer and @ypercube's have identical timestamps. +1 for both of you.

Comment: Is there any reason to keep the `id` field as primary key if this `unique key` thing is now set?

Comment: [Here's one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/should-every-table-have-a-single-field-surrogate-artificial-primary-key) related question on the matter of keeping the id field.

Comment: @Rolando: Actually DTest was faster by 1 second :)

Answer (score 6):

Change the table's definition by adding a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint on the combination of the two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20), 
     network_id int,
     network_contact_id int,
     CONSTRAINT network_id_contact_id_UNIQUE
       UNIQUE KEY (network_id, network_contact_id)
    );
```

---

You should also check this answer by Bill Karwin on the differences between [`INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: Why does your definition have the constraint in there when DTest's doesn't? What is the difference?

Comment: This is only providing a name for the constraint. If I remember well, with DTest answer, the constraint will be auto-named by MySQL.