# Is a surrogate key better than a natural key in this case

Tags: database-design, performance, index, best-practices, primary-key

I copied this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14184360/636342):

```
CREATE TABLE records(
    email TEXT REFERENCES users(email),
    lat DECIMAL,
    lon DECIMAL,
    depth TEXT,
    upload_date TIMESTAMP,
    comment TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (upload_date,email)
);

CREATE TABLE samples(
    date_taken TIMESTAMP,
    temp DECIMAL,
    intensity DECIMAL,
    upload_date TIMESTAMP,
    email TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(date_taken,upload_date,email),
    FOREIGN KEY (upload_date,email) REFERENCES records(upload_date,email)
);
```

The first thing that caught my eyes was the use of natural composite keys as primary keys for both tables.

3 things I was able to extract from this piece of code:

1. The `users` table (not shown here) uses `email` as primary key of type `text`..
2. The `records` table uses a composite key of `text` + `timestamp`.
3. The `samples` table uses a composite key of 3 fields of type `text`+ `timestamp`+ `timestamp`.

Now in this case wouldn't a surrogate key be better of identification? I mean performance wise indexing an `int` should be better than indexing a `text`? Is there something that could make a surrogate key a bad choice?

Comment: If this is for SQL Server, please see: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). And for SQL Server this wouldn't work - you **cannot** use a `TEXT` column in an index - an index entry can be **900 bytes** at most

Comment: Please remember: Even if you add a surrogate key, you still need to keep a UNIQUE, NOT NULL constraint on the original sets of columns in each table.  A surrogate key is just that, a surrogate, and does NOT say anything about the data. You will still need to look up these records using the natural composite keys in order to get the surrogate key and the original constraint needs to remain to keep the data consistent. As a result, you will actually increase insert/update/delete costs by adding the surrogate key, not reduce them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Email is a particularly bad choice for any PK whether composite or single.  See my answer on this question on Stack Overflow for why:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804108/is-email-address-a-bad-primary-key/3804174#3804174

Comment: @Songo - Certain "code table" values, especially those that are determined by a standards body, can be reasonable natural keys.  Think of "M" or "F" for gender, and things like currency and country codes.  Otherwise, surrogate keys are very often safer and better.

Answer (score 6):

I would consider two factors:

- Primary key values should not be subject to change or reuse.  Email addresses tend to be subject to change.  I generally use a surrogate for user ids in databases.
- Long strings tend to disrupt index key compression when they are not the first field in the index.  Depending on how the data is to be aggregated, this may be fixed by moving the email address to be the first field in the index.

Using a surrogate key which better represents the concept represented by the email address is likely a better solution.  Perhaps a field like contributer_id might be a better field.  An additional table translating email addresses to this field may be required.

EDIT: I have taken a second look at your design.  You may want to look at modeling sampling events (location, and time taken), samples, and email addresses.
Samples would be a child of sampling events.  A surrogate key on sampling events might be appropriate on the sampling events table to limit the number of columns in the key when it is migrated to the child table.

I don't know what you are sampling and how it is being aggregated.  How the data needs to be aggregated should be considered in the design.

Answer (score 3):

HLGEM and BillThor both make excellent points.  I would add that in addition to thinking about the stability of the key attributes and the efficiency of the key fields for index storage, there is one other factor to consider.

There is a trade-off that could impact performance when you are looking at your primary key fields.  Depending on how you define your key and how fast you add data, you might end up with a **hot spot** that slows you down.

For example, if you use an auto-increment integer surrogate key, very high transaction rates can result in contention for the active page of data.  This could limit the rate at which new data can be inserted.

On the other hand, if you use a natural key that has widely distributed values, then you need to make sure that you use a fill factor that leaves enough space for inserts.  If you have a fill factor of 100% then it effectively turns your whole table into a hot spot since the DBMS will have to move a bunch of rows to make room for an insert.

Comment: Actually , in newer versions of SQL Server (2005 and up), having a **insert hot-spot** at the "end" of a table with an ever-increasing clustering key (like an `INT IDENTITY`) is actually **beneficial** for performance. Why? Because those relevant pages are most likely already in cache if a next insert occurs. Hotspots were a big problem in earlier versions of SQL Server and their "myth" of being bad is still lingering around - without really being a problem anymore - quite the contrary!