# Performance impact of foreign key type in Mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

See this scenario

**Table: "user" -
Columns: id (primary key/unsigned int), email (unique/varchar), name(varchar)**

Now we also have a "order" table and two options of foreign key:

1. Foreign key order.user_email + user.email
2. Foreign key order.user_id + user.id

If we choose the first options instead of the second, are we going to have a negative performance impact (because the type of columns involved in the foreign key)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a surrogate key better than a natural key in this case](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31511/is-a-surrogate-key-better-than-a-natural-key-in-this-case)

Comment: I would like an answer more related to Mysql behavior

Comment: Why do you think that MySQL behaviour is different from other relational databases?

Comment: Because different databases can have different implementations of same abstraction that can cause different levels of positive/negative performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

A FK provides 2 things:

- An integrity check.  This means that an `INSERT` will verify that the corresponding row in some other table already exists.  This takes a small amount of time
- An `INDEX`.  An index is automatically added if there is not one already defined.  You probably need this index for other queries, so the performance hit for this is effectively zero.

Do the math.  How often are SQL queries being run?  If only 100 queries per second, you may have trouble measuring the CPU meter.  If 1000 per second, you may have issues.  I suspect that your app won't be bothered by the FK.