# Multiple one to many relationships in series

Tags: database-design, normalization

I am making a DB for storing reports that have following fields:

```
Ad_system,
Ad_Campaing,
Ad_Group,
Keyword,
Date,
Impressions,
Clicks,
Conversions
```

Logic is that, `Ad_system` can have multiple `Ad_Campaings`, `Ad_Campaing` can have multiple `Ad_Groups` and `Ad_Groups` can have multiple `Keywords`, and for every `Keyword` there is a `report`. Should It be like this? Because it kind of makes sense to me, but it doesn't look correct. Primary key can also be:

`ad.system.name` for first table

`ad.system.name ad.campaing.name` for second table

`ad.system.name ad.campaing.name ad.group.name` for third table

`ad.system.name ad.campaing.name ad.group.name keyword` for fourth table

They will always be unique, but then `Report` will always have all DB columns in it, so it's kind of redundant.  Is the approach that I have in the diagram below correct? Or is a better one what I just described? If I am not mistaken both should satisfy 3rd NF.

[image]

Comment: You spelled *campaign* wrong. Plus, I don't really get why you feel there is redundant data in `report` when there apparently **has to be** a report for every keyword.

Comment: If a report may have more than 1 keyword, it would be many to many relationship between report and keyword.

Comment: Your model seems to indicate that keywords only appear in one group and one campaign and one system.

I suspect that's not true, right?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct in the sense that both are normalized, based on your question. It seems like there isn't a strong consensus on whether to use natural keys or surrogate keys (the ids). Here are a couple of stackexchange questions on the subject:

- [Surrogate vs. natural/business keys [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys)
- [Should every table have a single-field surrogate/artificial primary key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/should-every-table-have-a-single-field-surrogate-artificial-primary-key)